# Achieve functionality of the mysql rand() function in R

Tags: mysql, r, random

I want to achieve the functionality of the mysql `rand()` function in R. Is there an equivalent function? More specifically, I want to achieve `rand(table_field)`. The value of the table field could be e.g. 11000004

[image]

Comment: take a look at `?runif`

Comment: For people who are not aware about `mysql` `rand` function (like me) could you explain what it does and what are it's characteristic?